What I misunderstanding about React states and context here?
This is the first part of my Next.js modal component, where I'm allowing a user to cancel or resume their subscription. I have a context, userAuth, which has functions to check the values of it's subscription.
When I try to cancel or resume a subscription, I can see behind the modal that the subscription info gets updated on the page. However, here are my logs running from the handleCancelSubscription function:
Running handleCancelSubscription, mode is  resume  userAuth?.getCancelDate() is  11/25/2024
Checking: mode is resume, userAuth?.getCancelDate() is 11/25/2024
Checking: mode is resume, userAuth?.getCancelDate() is 11/25/2024
...

You can see that when trying to resume, it's not checking or logging the new value of userAuth?.getCancelDate(). In the above example, on the modal itself I actually see the headline change to be Cancel instead of Resume. So I don't get why the function itself isn't seeing the new values. Any advice? Thanks!!
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Close } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { CircularProgress } from '@mui/material'
import { UserAuth } from '@/components/contexts/AuthContext'

interface CancelSubscriptionModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean
    setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

export default function CancelSubscriptionModal({ isOpen, setIsOpen }: CancelSubscriptionModalProps) {
    const userAuth = UserAuth()
    const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null)
    const mode = userAuth?.getCancelDate() ? 'resume' : 'cancel'

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false)
        setError(null)
    }
    

    const handleCancelSubscription = async () => {
        console.log('Running handleCancelSubscription, mode is ', mode)
        try {
            setIsProcessing(true)
            setError(null)

            const token = await userAuth?.user?.getIdToken()

            const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/modify-subscription`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ action: mode }),
            })

            if (response.ok) {
                const maxAttempts = 10
                let attempts = 0
                const interval = 3000 // 3 seconds

                while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
                    attempts++
                    console.log(`Attempt ${attempts}: Checking subscription status`)

                    await userAuth?.getSubscription(true)
                    let currentCancelDate = userAuth?.getCancelDate()

                    console.log(`Checking: mode is ${mode}, userAuth?.getCancelDate() is ${currentCancelDate}`)

                    if ((mode === 'cancel' && currentCancelDate) || (mode === 'resume' && !currentCancelDate)) {
                        console.log('Subscription updated successfully')
                        setIsOpen(false)
                        setIsProcessing(false)
                        return
                    }

                    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, interval))
                }

                setError('Subscription update timed out.')
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to modify subscription')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Operation failed:', error)
            setError('Something went wrong, please try again.')
        } finally {
            setIsProcessing(false)
        }
    }
    ...

    [JSX goes here]
    <span className="capitalize">{mode}</span> Your <span className="gradient-text">Subscription</span>
    ...
    [JSX ends here]



Within your handleCancelSubscription function mode is closed over and will never change, but your component is re-rendering during the async operation so you are seeing the value on the screen change. So this has nothing to do with state or context, but with a stale closure

@BrianThompson But I don't want 'mode' to update within the function actually - otherwise I'd imagine i could end up in a weird loop with the mode switching back and forth. I just want the latest userAuth?.getCancelDate() value.

@Max: If that value is maintained in state then it wouldn't be updated immediately.  State updates are batched and asynchronous.  If you're seeing the updated value on the next render then it's working.  It sounds like what you have is just an incorrect expectation.

@David Still very confused.
let currentCancelDate = userAuth?.getCancelDate() is referencing a context outside of the function, so why wouldn't that value be refreshed when userAuth is updated? Even though I do see the modal text update to fit the new userAuth.getCancelDate() state, and I see the main subscription page update.

@Max: If the code that's examining the value has a stale reference to an older object from state then that object wouldn't be updated.  State values are immutable.  A re-render elsewhere on the page may be showing updated data, and in the process of re-rendering it would have fetched a new reference to any objects which have that data.  Take a step back... What actual problem is this observation causing?  It may be surprising, even unintuitive, but it sounds like the page otherwise works as expected and the only problem is that you have a loop that's checking a value it doesn't need to check?

@David Ah interesting, I assumed because its using a context, it would grab the updated value. The problem is that if I can't get the updated to value, I can't know that the database has been updated via webhook (which is triggered by API call to /modify-subscription).
So with that in mind, what are my options to check the up-to-date userAuth?.getCancelDate()?

@Max: Do you need to be able to respond to that synchronously, or can you use that value in a useEffect triggered on the next render?  That’s generally how to respond to a change in a state value.
